# MySQL 8 can not restore dump

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I have a Databases and like to backup and restore my backups. My Database is more complex, but I will give a short example what is not working.

```
CREATE DATABASE `bug`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci; 
CREATE TABLE `bug`.`doc` ( `id` BIGINT, `xls` VARCHAR(16000) );
CREATE TABLE `bug`.`user` ( `id` BIGINT, `name` VARCHAR(16000) );
CREATE VIEW `bug`.`user_doc` AS (SELECT d.xls,u.name FROM `user` u JOIN doc d ON d.id = u.id);
```

I can backup the Database:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`bug` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */;
USE `bug`;
/*Table structure for table `doc` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `doc`;
CREATE TABLE `doc` (
  `id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `xls` varchar(16000) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*Data for the table `doc` */
/*Table structure for table `user` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16000) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*Data for the table `user` */
/*Table structure for table `user_doc` */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_doc`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `user_doc` */;
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_doc` */;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE  `user_doc`(
 `xls` varchar(16000) ,
 `name` varchar(16000) 
)*/;
/*View structure for view user_doc */
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_doc` */;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `user_doc` */;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `user_doc` AS select `d`.`xls` AS `xls`,`u`.`name` AS `name` from (`user` `u` join `doc` `d` on((`d`.`id` = `u`.`id`))) */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

but I can't restore the database. I get these Error:

```
Error Code: 1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

MySQL is creating a table user_doc that does not exist in my Database and wants to delete the table right after creating. I think MySQL is doing it because views can depend on views and the order of creating the views can be different. But now I can't import my dumpfile.

```
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE  `user_doc`(
 `xls` varchar(16000) ,
 `name` varchar(16000) 
)*/
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_doc` */;
```

How can I restore my Database without editing my dump?

Comment: If you delete those 5 lines, does it work?  Why do you use `varchar(16000)` instead of `text`?

Comment: With deleting the 5 lines then it works, but my databases are more complex. The varchar(16000) is only an example. My views depends on many table with varchar columns not with a lenght of 16000 but in sum of all columns it is more. It would work with text but I need to limit the columns lenght, with text I do not have a limit.

Comment: On what version was the dump taken?

Comment: Why does `user_doc` have two strings instead of having two ids?

Comment: The dump was taken with MySQL 8.0.34. The user_doc table is only an example to show the problem. If I need the strings to show them on a website or something else, when I need to get the strings. Why should I take the ids? If I take the Ids in the view, than I have to join with user and doc table again to get the strings.

This is only an example, the database Schema is working like it is. I can even take backups. But I cant restore the Backup. I cannot understand why it is possible to have a working database, but backup and restore is not working.

Comment: MySQL should not allow to create a view with a row size with more than 65535, but it does and it works. But Restoring a Backup does not work. Because the backup creates a table that does not exist. I did not create the table user_doc. I created a view user_doc. Why is the Backup creating the table user_doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh it is not a mysql bug. The dump was taken by an App called SQLYog. If I create the dump with mysql, then the table user_doc will not be created. If take the dump with SQLYog then the table user_doc will be created. So it is not a mysql bug, it is a bug of SQLYog (13.2.0).